# Why it doesn't yield memory-addresses when looping through a pointer?

Tags: c++

When we print `ptr`, it gives a memory address, but when we loop through it, we get array elements. What's causing the difference & why so?

```
int main()
{
    string texts[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
    string* ptr = texts;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << ptr[i];
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The difference is `[]`. As for why, read any C++ tutorial.

Comment: Your code doesn't print `ptr`

Comment: I don't get the question. What exactly is confusion you about printing different things yielding different results?

Comment: because ptr is a pointer, what do you expect to write other than an address ? `ptr[i]` on the other hand is equal to: `*(ptr + i)` so it gets a value in the given address, `pts + i`

Comment: Um... `ptr` and `ptr[i]` are two completely different things. So, why the question? Why do you find it strange that these two completely different things are interpreted differently?

Comment: I wouldn't say *any* tutorial. There are C++ tutorials out there that are so bad they could have OP trying to program in Cobol on an Antikythera and not know it.

Answer (score 0):

> When we print ptr, it gives a memory address, but when we loop through it, we get array elements.

`ptr` is a pointer so when you print it you get a memory address.

Note `ptr[i]` is the same as `*(ptr + i)`. So when you loop using array syntax `ptr[i]` you are dereferencing it and so you get the data itself.

Comment: Hello sir, Can you also refer me to any tutorial or source explaining why  ptr[i] is the same as *(ptr + i)

Comment: perhaps just google for C array vs pointer - read the first few articles that come up

Comment: @newbieman, That's the way the language is specified. Instead of having to do the pointer addition and dereference yourself, there is a nice `[]` syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `string* ptr= texts;` the starting address of the array is stored in the pointer memory i.e. the pointer now points to the starting address of the array. So, whenever you'll print `ptr`, an address will be printed.

But when you loop through it i.e. `ptr[I]` it's evaluated as `*(ptr+i)`.  * is the dereferencing operator which means it gives the value stored at the address given to it. Therefore, `*(ptr+i)` becomes the_value_at(location saved in ptr + i more units). Which is why you get array values.

Comment: in other-words, the [ ] is dereferencing that pointer, just like *?

Answer (score 0):

The type of `ptr` is `string*` - a pointer to a string. The type of `ptr[i]` is `string`.

`cout` is a global instance of class `ostream`. This class defines an insertion operator, i.e. `operator<<()` for `string` objects which specifically prints the contents of the string. Therefore `cout << ptr[i]` prints the text. On the other hand, `ostream` does not specifically define an insertion operator for pointers to strings. So the closest matching definition is `operator<<(void*)` - an insertion operator for pointers in general. This just prints the address.

Answer (score 0):

> ptr[i] is the same as *(ptr + i).

a container object like a string or an array is a pointer to the first element in that container. the [] operator access a certain object based on the starting location like @artm said. this question is the result of a lack of understanding how variable memory allocation works. look into that for a more complete answer.